# Delphi 7 + Zeos: how to prevent sqlite 3 converting date and integer/float to string?

Tags: delphi, sqlite, delphi-7, zeos

Test database:

```
create table a ( d date not null primary key);
create table b ( d date not null primary key);
insert into a values ('2013-01-01');
insert into b values ('2014-01-01');
```

Using Zeos lib with Delphi 7, these queries all return TDateTimeField:

```
select d from a order by 1;

select d from b order by 1;

select d from a union all select d from b;

select * from (select d from a union all select d from b) s;
```

However, this query returns a TStringField:

```
select * from (select d from a union all select d from b) s order by 1;
```

Questions:

- Why is that?
- How do I prevent this from happening?
- Is this a bug? How on earth ordering a result set changes the type of a column????
- This is a serious problem because I cannot generate SQL queries from my program and open them in a TZReadOnlyQuery that was created in design time

Update: it does not work with integers either.

```
create table c ( id integer not null primary key);
create table d ( id integer not null primary key);
insert into c values(1);
insert into d values(2);
```

These result in TLargeIntField:

```
select * from c order by 1

select * from d order by 1

select * from ( select * from c union all select * from d) s
```

However, this results in a TStringField:

```
select * from ( select * from c union all select * from d) s order by 1
```

Comment: The problem is clearly with "union all". With a simple "union", it does work correctly!

Comment: Same with REAL fields. I just checked. If I add an order by then it is changed from a TFloatField into a TStringField. Too bad.

Comment: I just tested this with Zeos 7.1.3-stable and it creates a TDateField and a TLargeintField as expected (in Delphi XE though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated here:http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

> SQLite **does not** have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"). 
> REAL as Julian
>   day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November
>   24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar. 
> INTEGER
>   as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>   Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
>   formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
>   time functions.

So, can you try the statement below and post the results?!

```
select date(*) as test from (select date(d) from a union all select date(d) from b) s order by 1;
```

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that SQLite stores only these three types internally. However, this type is automatically converted by the underlying zeos library! My question was asked specifically about Delphi 7 + Zeos lib + SQLite. So, if ZeosLib can convert date strings to TDateField field for a union select, then why can't it do the same for a union all select? Is there a way to write a query that does what I want? Of course I would not like to rewrite zeoslib.

Comment: Right. Which version of Zeos are you using?

Comment: I have no idea. This project was created with Delphi 7 several years ago. About in 2004. I would gladly upgrade to a newer version, but I'm affraid it would break all the other code. It must be something fundamental about union and order by. I just discovered that this problem also applies to real numbers! The are converted to TFloatField, unless I combine union with order by. Then they become strings. :-(

Comment: ok, please make that test above and tell me the results. I'm installing Zeos to try it out.

Comment: I just installed the latest ZeosLib on Delphi 7 and it did not break my code. Your query opens as a date field, fortunately. But here is the next problem: it still does not work with integers. (Will edit the question)

Comment: Here is a temporary solution - this is literally temporary:

drop table if exists _tmp;
create table _tmp as select ...... <my union all select here>;
select * from _tmp order by whatever_column;

The last select is used in the TZReadOnlyQuery, and all column types are just fine. So if anyone having this problem. I'm not satisfied with this solution, but at least it works!

Comment: Well not exactly because varchar(30) is converted to text->Memo but it is the best so far.